# What do you call someone who commits a traffic violation?

Tags: single-word-requests

People who commit crimes are criminals, people who commit felonies (heinous crime)  are felons, is there a specific word for people who commit traffic violations (minor crime) i.e. crosses a double yellow line, runs red light, etc. Is there a word for people who commit these types of infractions?

So for clarification, the violations I'm talking about are ones you would be ticketed from by a police officer, but would not receive jail time for. These violations are in the context of California law. Also, I am looking for a word that would describe someone who habitually commits these violations.

Sentence: X run the risk of getting ticketed, or even losing their licence, because they constantly ignore traffic laws.

Comment: It would help to have a little bit of context for your usage here; the basic term "violator" or "offender" would be fine if you want to refer to the person who committed a specific offense, but would likely not be appropriate if you want to indicate that they do so habitually.

Comment: There's three different classifications for crimes in the US: [felonies, misdemeanors, and infractions](http://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/crimes-felonies-misdemeanors-infractions-classification-33814.html). *Traffic violation* is not one of them.

Comment: @Mazura Infractions are not crimes.  Many traffic violations in California are infractions.

Comment: @deadrat - The point I forgot to make is that it varies from state to state, but it doesn't matter because it's one of those three. An infraction is not a crime? Intriguing... I'll have to research that further. Something to do with ordinances instead of laws?

Comment: @Mazura No, it has to do with criminal procedure.  For instance, no jury trial or guaranteed counsel for you if you're accused of an infraction.  But no jail time either.  At least in CA.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz does the edit help, or is more information needed?

Comment: @Dragonrage it doesn't help, because it doesn't answer the question I asked; are you looking for a word to describe someone who does these things habitually? Or a word to refer to the perpetrator of a specific infraction. For example: "the speed limit in this school zone is 15. Violators *will* be ticketed" is a valid usage, but you wouldn't call those people 'violators' in the general sense outside of discussion of their infraction, the way you might a felon. That's the distinction I'm trying to draw out here.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz oh, sorry, I am looking for a word that would describe someone who habitually does this. I shall update the question with this information.

Comment: @Mazura better?

Comment: I would call such a naughty minx, "Miss Demeanor."

Comment: 'Minor crime' is arguable in some cases. Running a red light may result in manslaughter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could consider using [**habitual traffic offender**](http://www.dol.wa.gov/driverslicense/suspendhto.html) for someone who habitually commits those violations you mentioned. According to Washington State Department of Licensing (reference is not available on California DMV), it is defined as:

> A driver who, within a 5-year
> period, has been:
>
> Convicted of 3 or more offenses listed in RCW 46.65.020(1).
>
> or
>
> Found
> to have been convicted of or committed **20 or more moving violations**
> listed in WAC 308-104-160. The violations must have occurred within a
> 5-year period. If more than 1 of these offenses are committed within a
> 6-hour period, they’re only counted as 1 on the first occasion.

[The Law Place](http://theticketlawyers.com/criminal-traffic-violations/habitual-traffic-offender.html) defines it as:

> ... and receiving **15 or more moving violations** within five years.

[Moving violations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_violation):

> A moving violation is any violation of the law committed by the driver
> of a vehicle **while it is in motion**. The term "motion" distinguishes it
> from other motor vehicle violations, such as paperwork violations
> (which include violations involving automobile insurance, registration
> and inspection), parking violations, or equipment violations.

[Wikipedia]

Comment: Interesting. I was somewhat hoping for a single word to describe it, but if none exist, this is probably the best phrase that has the meaning I want.

Comment: @Dragonrage IMHO, the reason there is not a single word is that it is not very often used like felon, petty criminals, or juvenile (young) offenders, etc. I mean everybody is a traffic offender in a way and it is not a serious crime. **Traffic offender** is the term, I think. :-)

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest, ***minor offender***.

> minor offense: *noun* A criminal infraction less serious than a misdemeanor. These infractions may not even be tracked as part of a criminal record, depending on state and local laws. Generally, these types of infractions carry penalties of monetary fines and/or up to 90 days in jail. Depending on the state and local statutes, an example of a minor offense is a parking violation or traffic (driving) offense.
> [YourDictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/minor-offense#vouzGAQXZ7A8JBFG.99)

In light of your edit, consider [*minor*] [***traffic scofflaw***](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22traffic+scofflaws%22&biw=466&bih=306&prmd=ivmn&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIoOS5sqvKAhUKnBoKHWaADrMQ_AUICygG).

> scofflaw:
>
> One who habitually violates laws, especially laws that do not involve serious criminal offenses. [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/scofflaw)
>
> A contemptuous law violator [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scofflaw)
>
> ***Traffic scofflaws** run the risk of getting ticketed, or even losing their license, because they constantly ignore traffic laws*.

Comment: You can't go to jail over an infraction in California, where infractions are violations of statues but aren't a criminal matter. Don't make me look up the other 50 jurisdictions.  Or go outside US law.

Comment: @Elian - You don't seem to have filled in the example sentence correctly. Surely it should be "**Traffic scofflaws** run the risk of getting ticketed because they routinely ignore traffic laws"?

Comment: A *minor offender* sounds like someone who is under the legal age. [*As we can see, American and French procedures are not so different, just because they have a common goal, protect as much as possible **minor offender’s** interest.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparative_juvenile_criminal_law#Functioning_of_juvenile_criminal_justice)

Answer (score 2):

You may call this person a *misdemeanant*. Definition:

> A person convicted of a misdemeanor or guilty of misconduct.

Definition of *misdemeanor*:

> A minor wrongdoing.

You may also call this person an *infractor*. Definition:

> One that infracts or infringes: violator, lawbreaker

(Oxford Dictionaries Online: [misdemeanant](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/misdemeanant), [misdemeanor](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/misdemeanor))

(Merriam-Webster: [infractor](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/infractor))

Comment: Who says either of those? No one I've ever heard.

Comment: A traffic violation is *not* a misdemeanor. A misdemeanor is substantially more severe.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz  [_Moving violation_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_violation) Wikipedia article: "Moving violations are usually classified as infractions or misdemeanors."

Comment: @Kyle note the use of **or** there. Misdemeanor traffic offenses are generally quite severe, and can often carry jail time.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz The fact is that a moving violation _can be_ a misdemeanor. My answer covers both types of moving violations (_misdemeanant_ or _infractor_).

Comment: @Kyle it could be - but it's very clearly *not* the sort of violation being asked about in this question.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz - I think you're confusing parking tickets with moving violations, which is what running a red light is. OP needs to clarify I think. I don't think you get charged with a "traffic violation". You either "got a parking ticket" or you're brought up on misdemeanor charges. Or go 25mph over and it's a felony.

Comment: @Mazura Not in California.  Violations of the vehicle code are by default infractions, with exceptions made for misdemeanors and felonies.  For instance, failure to follow the instructions of someone directing traffic or failure to obey signs and signals is an infraction, unless the failure is willful.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the term **transgressor**

Examples from the net

> - *The fliers also list how much a **transgressor** would have to pay if ticketed, and warn that real tickets will be passed out in the future if parking laws continue to be ignored,...*
> - *Whether a frequent offender or occasional **transgressor**, parking fines can be paid easily through Ticketzen, a mobile app that only requires motorists to scan a ticket bar code to pay it off via credit or debit card.*
> - Third Stage: *If 24 and 34 points are accumulated, the **transgressor** is required to attend a special course on driver safety.*
> - Red-faced officials from the department of justice and the department of transport are working to scrap the amendment in the Criminal Procedure Act, which stipulates that a traffic officer can arrest **a road transgressor** only after getting the go-ahead from a magistrate.
> - *Edinburgh City Council must back up its rhetoric and ensure all companies are aware of their obligations and to use every power available to name and shame them and maximise the fines for **transgressors**.*

If the infraction involves [flouting](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/flout?q=flouting) the speed limit, the driver can be called a **speeding motorist**

If the transgressor is a **repeat offender** then I would suggest the following:

1. **[Regular transgressors](http://www.kslegislature.org/li_2014/b2013_14/committees/ctte_h_corr_juv_jus_1/documents/testimony/20140128_01.pdf)** run the risk of getting ticketed, or even losing their licence, because they constantly ignore traffic laws.
2. Having more police on the roads, stopping and awarding black points to those who break the rules, will force **[repeat transgressors](http://www.thenational.ae/opinion/editorial/put-new-drivers-on-probation)** to rethink their behaviour.
3. **[Frequent transgressors](http://mycouncil.surreycc.gov.uk/documents/s15332/Freight%20Initiatives%20Update.pdf)** who park in residential area are first
   made aware of their obligations and asked to move. Ultimately they can
   be reported to the Traffic Commissioner who can revoke their licence.
4. **[Repeat offenders](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/repeat-offender)** run the risk of getting ticketed, or even losing their licence, because they constantly ignore traffic laws.

Answer (score 1):

In the UK some traffic violations (e.g. speeding) are technical crimes (example: speeding), known as traffic offences, and some are merely administrative offences (example: driving in a bus lane). I doubt however that a layman would refer to someone who had been caught driving at 35 mph in a 30 mph zone as a 'criminal' unless it was an attempt at humour. I suspect there are similar jurisdictional complexities elsewhere.

The layman's word we would use for both would be *'offender'*.

Answer (score 0):

A ***petty*** criminal, perhaps.

Petty - Of secondary or lesser importance, rank, or scale; minor; subordinate (OED)

Comment: I think of a petty criminal who picks pockets or steals office supplies, not a traffic offender. Um, there's your word.

Comment: "[Improper Lane Usage](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=improper%20lane%20usage) is a **petty offense**, punishable up to a $1000 fine in addition to Court Supervision for up to 24 months. A ticket for Improper Lane Usage often arises from a traffic accident." A *petty offender*.

Comment: @Mazura - I reckon that's better.  Post it and I'll vote for it.

Comment: Just a suggestion; all you, Dan.